# Will an AT&T iPad purchased from Best Buy US work in india?

Tags: ipad, unlock, cellular-carriers

I am planning to purchase iPad Mini wifi + cellular from Best Buy. The Best Buy representatives were not sure it will work in India with different service provider or not.

They are selling iPad with the service provider locked with AT&T or Verizon (as I was told, anyway).

If I purchase, from Best Buy, a wifi + cellular AT&T iPad, will that work in India or do I need to buy an unlocked iPad from Apple store?

I never have heard that iPads are locked. Are they?

Comment: You will have to get an AT&T international plan.

Comment: Do you want to use a local SIM (from an Indian provider) in India or keep using your American SIM? The later might result in high costs for any data transfers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a US bought iPad (newest) on Verizon work in India?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74702/will-a-us-bought-ipad-newest-on-verizon-work-in-india)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options.

First you will have to have AT&T unlock your device.

Then you will need to find a provider in India that will support your device.

Alternately (but costly) is to open an International roaming account with AT&T.

Check here:

http://www.wireless.att.com/learn/international/roaming/travel-guide.jsp?

Technically speaking, you device will work in India.

Check here

http://www.wireless.att.com/travelguide/coverage/roaming/step3.jsp?CIDL=356&CTN=&MNC=SHOP&DID1=468&DID2=&devicenum=1&STEP=3

Comment: Thanks For the update so even though ipad are not locked still in order to use in india we need to first get it unlocked by service provider in US

Answer (score 0):

no just take out your at&t sim it will work fine with any other carrier.

Comment: How would this solve any SIM/Net locking which might be in place?

Answer (score 0):

my AT&T iPad Mini is SIM locked to the AT&T network and AT&T refuses to unlock it. The website http://www.att.com/deviceunlock claims the device cannot be unlocked and 2 calls to AT&T tech support say the same thing.

It's not a technical matter, it's an AT&T service policy (best I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is that it is not locked to that given service provider, then it will work in India for sure but if you want cellular data then I advise you to ask apple for the bands of network and the frequencies that that given iPad piece can read.